# changing specific fields in linked list using iterator

Tags: java

This is the last thing my specs say I need to do 
 //ToDo 8 - Iterate over your remaining fishes and change all the data
      System.out.println("Show your setters working:\n");

Im not sure how to do this, I was trying to test out the .set method for linked lists but the thing that confuses me is the fact that there are multiple fields in each element so I cant just write fl.add(index, element)  I just need to know how to change the data in each field of the element and then I can make another iterator and do the rest.  here is my code

Fishdata class

```
    public class FishData {
    private String species;  //species of fish
    private int minSize;  //min size allowed in inches
    private String season;  //fishing season
    private int limit;  //number
    private Boolean willEat;
    //constructor
    FishData(String s1, int m, String s2, int I, Boolean w){
        species = s1;
        minSize = m;
        season = s2;
        limit = I;
        willEat = w;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return species + "" + minSize + "" + season + "" + limit + "" + willEat;
    }
    public String getSpecies(){
        return this.species;
    }
    public String getSeason(){
        return this.season;
    }
    public Boolean getWillEat(){
        return this.willEat;
    }
    public int getminSize() {
        return this.minSize;
    }
    public int getLimit() {
        return this.limit;
    }


    public void setSpecies(String species) {
        this.species = species;
    }
    public void setSeason(String season) {
        this.season = season;
    }
    public void setWillEat(Boolean willEat) {
        this.willEat = willEat;
    }
    public void setminSize(int minSize) {
        this.minSize = minSize;
    }
    public void setlimit(int limit) {
        this.limit = limit;
    }

}
```

main class

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Iterator;
public class GoneFishin {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //create linked list of fish data called fl
        LinkedList<FishData> fl = new LinkedList<FishData>();
        //Here are a few data items
        fl.add(new FishData("American Eel ", 9, "Summer/Spring ", 25, false));
        fl.add(new FishData("Hammerhead Shark ", 0, "All Year ", 36, false));
        fl.add(new FishData("Horseshoe Crab ", 7, "All Year except May ", 60, false));
        fl.add(new FishData("Haddock ", 18, "All Year ", 0, true));
        fl.add(new FishData("Tautog ", 16, "late Spring to end of year ", 3, true));

        for (FishData element : fl) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
        System.out.print("SIZE OF LISTt: ");
        System.out.println(fl.size());

        System.out.print("SECOND ELEMENT IN LIST: ");
        System.out.println(fl.get(1));

        System.out.print("LAST ELEMENT IN LIST: ");
        System.out.println(fl.getLast());

        Iterator<FishData> itr2 = fl.iterator();

        System.out.println("PRINTING ALL ELEMENTS USING ITERATOR");
        while (itr2.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(itr2.next());
        }
        Iterator<FishData> itr = fl.iterator();
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            FishData b = (FishData) itr.next();
            if (b.getWillEat()== false) {
                itr.remove();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("FISH THAT ARE GOOD TO EAT");
        for (FishData element : fl) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
     fl.set(1,"Shrekfish", 19, "whenever it wants", 7, false);


 }
}
```

i know that fl.set at the end doesnt work its giving me an error im just trying to figure out how it does work so i was testing that.

Comment: Given some iteration over the remaining fish, you will get a `FishData` just like you did in the test for `b.getWillEat()`. Then for each `b` instead of calling a `.getX()` you would call a `.setX(val)`. You are not calling a set on the `LinkedList` but on each element of the list. If I understood your question correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change it to

```
fl.set(1, new FishData("Shrekfish", 19, "whenever it wants", 7, false));
```

*If I understood your question correctly. This will replace the element at index `1` with a new Object

If you just want to update individual elements then

```
for (FishData element : fl) {
    element.setminSize (28);  // or whatever
    System.out.println(element);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After the `fl` (which is a linked list) has been pared down by removing certain fish, it seems like the task is to iterate any remaining fish, and call setters on them. So, something like:

```
for (FishData element : fl) {
  element.setSeason("Winter, Summer, Spring, or Fall");
}
```

The idea is to update the values of each remaining element, if I understood the question.